# How to highlight table cells after checking a condition using JavaScript function whose values are fed by XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am new to `JavaScript` and I want to highlight table row if the values are not the same throughout the row knowing that I use a loop to extract the values from the `XML` file using `XSLT`. How can I do that?

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="./projects/project">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="weight"/>
        <xsl:variablename="compare"select="weight"/>
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to store the variable `compare` in an `array`. Then loop through it and check if all the values are equal. Otherwise, I need to use `JavaScript` to highlight the row.
This code does not include `JavaScript`, I just don't know how to incorporate with `XSLT`.

Comment: The XSL you had posted so far has nothing to do with javascript. Why do you think you need javascript for this? Can you edit your question and clarify _exactly_ what you are trying to achieve? Post the HTML you would like to see.

Comment: Yes it has no JAVASCRIPT.. I want to store the variables "compare" in an array using javascript..then loop through it and check if all the values are equal otherwise I need to use javascript to highlight the row. This code does not include javascript, I just dont know how to incorporate it with XSLT.
I hope I am clear enough.
Thank you..

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an example how to use XSLT to create a page with javascript functions in it.

Comment: if the values to compare are in some XML tree (you have not posted any input sample) you could generate the table with some @class on td if they have the same value. I will post an example later.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an existing example of using XSLT and Javascript together**.

This transformation produces an html page with javascript in which pressing on a number-button produces the square of that number:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">
<!-- squareAsHTMLJS1.xml: create an HTML document with JavaScript that
     interactively computes the square of each "number" element read from 
     the source tree. -->

  <xsl:template match="/"> <!-- Set up web page -->
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Squares</title>
         <script language="JavaScript1.2">
           function showSquare(n) {
            alert("the square is " + n*n);
           }
        </script>
        <style> <!-- Put a little CSS in -->
           body { font-family: arial,helvetica; }
           h1   { font-size: 14pt }
           p    { font-size: 10pt}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Squares</h1>
        <p>Click a button to see the square of that number.</p>
        <form>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="number">
    <p><input type="button" value=" {.} " onClick="showSquare({.})"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<numbers>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>11</number>
  <number>100</number>  
  <number>-5</number>
</numbers>
```

**the result is**:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>Squares</title><script language="JavaScript1.2">
           function showSquare(n) {
            alert("the square is " + n*n);
           }
        </script><style> 
           body { font-family: arial,helvetica; }
           h1   { font-size: 14pt }
           p    { font-size: 10pt}
        </style></head>
   <body>
      <h1>Squares</h1>
      <p>Click a button to see the square of that number.</p>
      <form>

         <p><input type="button" value=" 2 " onClick="showSquare(2)"></p>

         <p><input type="button" value=" 11 " onClick="showSquare(11)"></p>

         <p><input type="button" value=" 100 " onClick="showSquare(100)"></p>

         <p><input type="button" value=" -5 " onClick="showSquare(-5)"></p>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can play with this here: **http://www.snee.com/xml/trxml33/numbersJS1.xml**

And see more explanations by the author here: **http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/02/05/tr.html**

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="numbers">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>.all-equal {background-color:yellow;}</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates>
                            <xsl:with-param name="all-equal"
                            select="not(number[1] != number[position()!=1])"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="number">
        <xsl:param name="all-equal"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="$all-equal">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">all-equal</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<numbers>
  <number>20</number>
  <number>20</number>
  <number>20</number>
</numbers>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>.all-equal {background-color:yellow;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="all-equal">20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="all-equal">20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="all-equal">20</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```